# New Google Earth app max overlay texture size reduced?

Tags: kml, google-earth, kmz

With the latest update of Google Earth on iPhone 6s plus, a kmz file containing a JPEG overlay reference is shown with red X. In the previous version, the overlay was shown correctly.

The problem should be tied to available memory not enough to show jpeg. Probably the new version leaves less free memory for overlay.

I would like to know if the maximum size for a pixel overlay is known for the new iOS android apps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the details of max texture sizes in the new Google Earth, but one thing to check first is whether your image is hosted externally to the KML/KMZ file, and if it is, make sure it's being reference via HTTPS (not HTTP), since plain HTTP requests will not return the image.

If the image is internal to the KMZ, can you share a copy so we can take a look? Or at least tell us the pixel dimensions of the image?